# Select all occurrences of a word in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Simple question: I am looking for the shortcut in WebStorm to select all the occurrences of a word and then replace them

e.g in my CSS file I want to select all the 'phone' variables at once and change them to 'tab-port'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> for find and replace. This will open up a dialog at the top of the file that will look similar to the following: (depending on your IDE theme)

[image: find-and-replace-dialog]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all occurrences directly in the code, you can select all of them with the next shortcut:

`Ctrl` + `Cmd` + `G` on Mac OS X or 
`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `J` on Windows

If you want to replace all occurrences, you can make as [chazsolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4095444/chazsolo) said.